# Can a logarithm to a fractional base have an integral result?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms

Consider the following setup. Let $b > 1$ be a fractional base, i.e. $b \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{N}$. My question is whether there could potentially exist an $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\log_b(x) = y \in \mathbb{N}$.

The existence of such an $x$ would seem odd to me as that would imply $b^y = x$ for a fractional $b$ and integral $x, y$. I can't seem to think of a proof though. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You don't believe there is a $b$ that solves the equation $b^2 = 2$?

Comment: Is $b$ non-integer or fractional more specifically?

Comment: If by "fractional" you mean $\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb Z$, then indeed $b^n$ can't be an integer for $n\in\mathbb N$. However, for $b\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z$ this is not the case, as Davids example of $(\sqrt 2)^2=2$ shows.

Comment: yup, sorry for the confusion, I meant fractional as in $\mathbb{Q}$, sorry for the confusion! -- updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any positive rational that isn't an integer can be written as $b=\frac p q$ for coprime integers $p\ge 1$, $q>1$. Then for $y\in\mathbb N$
$$
b^y = \frac{p^y}{q^y},
$$
where $p^y$ and $q^y$ are still coprime so that $b^y\in\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb Z$.